# Cannot enter multiline statements in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-platform

```
let x=1
    y=2
    z=3
```

does not work in GHCi, forcing me to use `let {x=1;y=2;y=3}` instead. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 12):

[The documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) says:

> GHCi also has a multiline mode, enabled by :set +m, in which GHCi detects automatically when the current statement is unfinished and allows further lines to be added. A multi-line input is terminated with an empty line.

The multiline mode makes GHCi behave much like e.g. the Python interpreter:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude|     y = 2
Prelude|     z = 3
Prelude|
Prelude> (x, y, z)
(1,2,3)
```

This hidden gem is wonderful for playing with readable code!

If you want this to be the default behaviour, you can create a `.ghci` file in your home directory with a line saying `:set +m`. (Now that this came up, I actually did so.)