# How to fix "error: parse error on input ‘=’" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm just trying to see if WinGHCi works for Haskell programming, and I don't know the reason why this shows the error above.

I do not know if this is the right application to work on Haskell, if you know another one that can actually work, I would appreciate.

```
f (x:xs) = f ys ++ [x] ++ f zs
 where
 ys = [a | a ← xs, a ≤ x]
 zs = [b | b ← xs, b > x]
```

```
<interactive>:21:20: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Comment: That's declaration syntax, for files, not ghci.

Comment: You want to read the [GHCi manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html). Also possibly upgrade your Haskell installation if it's older than version 8.

Comment: @melpomene isn't this supported since GHC 8 or so?

Comment: @n.m. not multi-line. Also, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162420/cannot-enter-multiline-statements-in-ghci

Comment: @AJFarmar `:set` +m perhaps? Note the question is from 2013.

Comment: Does `:set +m` let you use `where`? My (admittedly few) attempts all ended with parse errors on `where`.

Comment: @chepner it works but you need to put `where` on the first line: `foo = bar where <enter> bar = 42`

Comment: Ah, because you need something that a line can't otherwise end with, right?

Answer (score 3):

There are two intertwined issues: whether you need `let` to introduce a definition, and whether you can write a multiline definition.

First, `let`. Prior to 8.0, GHCi required a definition be introduced with `let`:

```
let f (x:xs) = ...
```

Starting in 8.0, you can drop the `let`, and GHCi will figure out what you are trying to do.

As for the multiline statement, there are two ways you can do this. One is to explicitly delimit your block with `:}` and `:{`:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| f (x:xs) = f ys ++ [x] ++ f zs
Prelude|  where
Prelude|  ys = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
Prelude|  zs = [b | b <- xs, b > x]
Prelude| :}
```

The other, enabling multiline mode with `:set +m`, appears to be picker about what it accepts.